# Matlab variable which stores the name of the mfile and line number

Tags: matlab

For debugging purpose, I want to print out the name of the m-file and the line number so that, when something goes off, it says something like

```
Error at 197th line of run.m
```

Given that Matlab displays an error message of this type, there must be a solution.

How can I do this?

===========Follow-up question==============

Thank you! But I got a follow-up question.

I have main.m which is the main m-file and main.m calls lower.m

I wrote

```
info = dbstack()
```

and

```
try 
    error('Toto')
catch ME
    ME.stack
end
```

to the main.m. Then Matlab displays

```
info = 

    file: 'main.m'
    name: 'main'
    line: 15

ans = 

    file: 'C:\Users\account1\Google Drive\1AAA-RA\11HHJK(O…'
    name: 'main'
    line: 18
```

However, when I write dbstack and try-catch thing to lower.m, then Matlab does not display any exact information.

I ran the main.m and main.m called the lower level m-file but it doesn't display any information.

```
info = 

2x1 struct array with fields:

    file
    name
    line

ans = 

2x1 struct array with fields:

    file
    name
    line
```

What should I do to make it display every file, name, line information?

Ideally, Matlab will display the information of both main.m and lower.m like the following:

```
    file1: 'main.m'
    name1: 'main'
    line1: 15
    file2: 'lower.m'
    name2: 'lower'
    line2: 6
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you have the information available in the structure : _info = **2x1 struct** array with fields:_. Try to type `info(1)` in the command window. Also, read a bit about accessing [`structure`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) fields...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Matlab Exception object. The line information is contained in the 'stack' property.

Example create a 'test.m' script:

```
try
    error('Toto')
catch ME
    ME.stack
end
```

Output of command window is:

```
>> test

ans = 

    file: 'D:\MATLAB\Sandboxes\AVLab\test.m'
    name: 'test'
    line: 2
```

Or without a try/catch you can use MException.last.

See documentation link http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/capture-information-about-errors.html

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works. But it didn't work when I write it to a lower-level m-file. I ran the main.m and main.m called the lower level m-file but it doesn't display any information.

Answer (score 1):

```
info = dbstack();

% info is now a struct that has 3 fields

% info.file
% is a string containing the file name in which the function appears.

% info.name 
% is a string containing the name of the function within the file.

% info.line
% is the line number on which dbstack was called
```

Comment: Thank you again Toothpick Aemone! Your solution works. But it didn't work when I write it to a lower-level m-file. I ran the main.m and main.m called the lower level m-file but it doesn't display any information.

Answer (score -1):

MATLAB's error function will automatically display the filename and line number.

```
function [ ] = wsgefiow9ey(  )
n = 7;
if n > 1
    msg = 'Error: n is too big.';
    error(msg)
end % if
end % function definition
```

[click here to see console output resulting from call to MATLAB error function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDY9r.png)

Comment: Thank you! But dispalying it on screen won't be enough. I want to store it to a variable and print this out as an excel file. I know how to create an excel file from matlab. I just don't know how to store the name of m-file and line number to a variable.